# Tag score is shown incorrectly in the next badge tracker section

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-badges, badge-progress

In the last couple of days, I have noticed that the tag score is not getting reflected correctly in the tag badge tracker area. This seems to have coincided with the introduction of a new privilege level at 25k rep and with it, the choice of tracking either the next privilege level (or) a tag badge.

In the below screenshot, my score in the [css-shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-shapes) is shown as 602 from a total of 105 answers.

[image]

But as can be seen from the Tags section of the profile page, my actual score in the tag is 607 from a total of 106 answers.

[image]

This problem is only seen in the **Next tag badge** box in the profile page. The overlay where we can select the tag badge to track displays the correct value.

[image]

**Note:** I have tried after clearing the cache and there is no change. I have checked the mobile site and the same problem is seen there also.

---

**Update:** I got past the 25k rep mark today morning and can confirm that the scores are now getting updated near real-time. It can't be just a coincidence and so I strongly feel there is a problem which is affecting users who have the option of tracking privilege (or) tag badge.

Comment: It _is_ caching- Server-side caching, hence why it was the same on the mobile site and why clearing _your_ cache didn't affect the value. Plenty of things on the profile are cached server-side, including the badge trackers.

Comment: [Blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @Kendra: I understand and it is very much possible. The count seems to get updated properly at the end of the day but just not during the day (the near real-time tracking). I have never seen this caching problem before the introduction of the track privilege/tag badge option and wondering if that new option is causing any impact.

Comment: Even now the count hasn't got updated through the day but it did get updated overnight (the old end of day update process). So I am not sure if this is any caching issue.

Comment: My angular badge progress has been two answers behind for several days now. Just not moving anymore.

Comment: @m59: Need to check if users below 20k have this option of tracking next privilege (or) next tag badge. I feel the problem is affecting only users between 20k - 25k rep range.

Comment: I re-selected the same badge for progress tracking and it updated.

Comment: @m59 Strange that your previous comment didn't trigger any notifications. I tried the same and it works only in the morning (IST) after the job is run for the day. During the day, that still makes no difference. I am waiting to see what happens once I get past 25k.

Comment: I got past the 25k mark today morning and can confirm that now the scores are getting updated near real-time. It can't be just a coincidence and so I strongly feel there is a problem which is affecting users who have the option of tracking privilege (or) tag badge.

Comment: The score updates as expected in the "tags" section of the very same web page. I can't think of any reason the badge tracker couldn't pull its number from exactly the same place.

Comment: It's still affecting me. The only way my count ever updates is if I re-track the badge. I'm nearing 25k, but not there yet.

Comment: @m59: Currently the only fix seems to be to get past 25k. I haven't seen this problem ever since I got past that mark.

Comment: When this will be fixed?

Comment: How on earth getting over 25k would resolve server caching...?

Comment: @Thomas: It isn't a server caching issue (some were too quick to dismiss this as a non-issue). The thing is that 25k is the highest privilege level on SO and above that one gets the ability to only track tag badges (nomore privileges to track). So, with that the tracked badge's score is getting updated correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was an issue where a tracked tag badge's progress wouldn't get updated when you viewed your profile.  This has now been fixed.

I didn't catch it, as the unit tests didn't use a user that still had privileges; this has been also fixed.

Note that there's still around 10 minutes of caching each time you view your own profile between updates.

I am sorry for this bug - this is how I feel about it:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much for the fix and the confirmation :)

Comment: You don't appear to be sorry enough.

Comment: @Matt I am. [This is me, reevaluating my choice to be a programmer](http://i.imgur.com/9imDLD5.gifv), after realizing how stupid this bug was.

Answer (score 28):

I really hesitated to comment and/or answer, and/or respond to this bug to report a "me too". I so much hesitated that I even [asked on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308412/5239503) what was expected from me... So please forgive me if I shouldn't have had reported this this way.

Anyway, just to tell that I'm (very very) far from reaching 25k, and that this bug affects me on all machines and web Browsers I've tried: Firefox 41.0.2 and 42.0b8 on Linux, Chrome 46.0.2490.71 on Linux, Firefox 41.0.2 on Windows, and Android browser on Android 4.4.2.

There, the "next tag badge" tracker gets never (ever) updated (I saw it stay the same for nearly one month) unless I manually select another badge to track. Then the newly selected badge is up-to-date, but do not get updated either. So I understand that this data can be cached server-side, but that is a bit of extreme caching if you ask me.

Anyway, if you need some specific test to help you track this down, just let me know.

Comment: Let's hope it gets more attention but I can definitely say it gets solved once we cross the 25k (highest privilege level) mark.

Comment: I have to manually "update" it by tracking another badge and then switch back to tracking my wanted badge. It does display the correct numbers then.

Comment: @Adriaan it does for me as well, but only right after the switch back. From there, the value doesn't get updated automatically as the the "scores" evolve following to new answers and upvotes... Does it for you?

Comment: @Gilles Nope. They are "stuck" at the number right after updating, until you manually renew it again.

Comment: Thanks for that @Gilles changing the badges does update it, but not completely .. my stats on the badge are still incorrect... my score has been stuck on 99 for a while.

Comment: This should now be fixed - my apologies.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, and I have it for a long time.

[image]

By debugging a bit, I noticed the outdated value comes directly in the html (it's not AJAX):

[image]

In which I get:

```
<div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="label">19/100 score</div>
        <div class="bar">
            <div class="percent" style="width: 19%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This should now be fixed - my apologies.