# What's the right approach for a "me too" report of a bug?

Tags: discussion

I recently experienced a bug on SO and found that it has been reported already, but apparently with limited attention. Since I'm not familiar with bug reporting on SO-meta and since I do not want to make any blunder, I though I'll check what behaviour is expected in such cases. So I looked at the help, the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag description, did a search on the site, etc. All this to no avail so that I'm still puzzled.

Then I figured that since we're on SO, I'd better be asking; and here is the question:

When I find a bug on the site, which was already reported but not clearly acknowledged, what should be my course of action?

1. Up-voting the question/bug report?
2. Commenting with a "me too"-like comment?
3. Answering the question/bug report with extra details on how it affects me?
4. Opening a new bug?

I would be naturally tempted to do both 1. and 2., but I'm not sure that's the right thing to do.

---

**EDIT**: I gave this question 48h or so just to see if a consensus would appear, and here is what I gather from this: all in all, there's no clear answer. However, I guess that what everyone said here can be summarised in these few words: "be responsible and trust your best judgement"... Because ultimately, it depends on the circumstances: how critical is the bug, the number of previous "me too" reported, how old it is, whether some new informations can be given...

So that's what I'll do: trust my best judgement and try to be helpful for the community. Thank you for those who expressed their opinion, either by a comment, an answer or a vote.

After having hesitated, I chose to upvote + [answer with extra details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308621/5239503)

Comment: You could upvote the question, but I doubt that's a (big) factor in which bugs get fixed with the limited developer resources. A comment or answer is just noise if it's literally "I'm also having this problem" without any new information. If you've got new information then it depends on the scope, I'd say: if you're just saying that it also affects Browser X version Y, comment. If you've got an in-depth explanation of how to reproduce it, that would be useful as an answer.

Comment: I'd go with option 4, as many websites index the severity of the bug depending on how often it has been reported. I know that apple's **rdar** does this, but I'm not sure whether SO does too.

Comment: I think confirming that the bug is reproducible is helpful if no one else has already said so but I think #3 would be the most useful thing to do.

Comment: Offer a bounty.

Comment: ` A comment or answer is just noise if it's literally "I'm also having this problem" without any new information.` I hear this a lot, but, as someone who has been on the receiving end of bug reports, I don't agree. A couple of me-too responses makes it very clear (to me) that this is not an isolated incident but is a more widespread issue. I would also probably give it more priority in such cases. Of course adding additional info makes it that much more useful. E.g: `I'm also having this problem on Chrome for Windows v44.xy.z`.

Comment: @kabiroberai I'm pretty sure duplicate bug reports just get closed as duplicate questions using the standard criteria (when they were posted, the relative quality of each post, etc.). Whether or not SE's bug tracker does anything extra with that data I don't know.

Comment: @Oriol No bounties on per-site metas, I think? It's an option for the overall meta.stackexchange.com, if you have sufficient reputation over there.

Answer (score 14):

It really depends on the bug, its severity, and the length of time from when it was previously reported.

If the bug was *reported a year or more ago*, just post a new question. Don't do this if it was asked recently as it just creates noise. Re asking if the issue is old is preferable for the team because of multiple reasons.

- The version of the exchange may be greatly different now versus the original issue
- Asking a new question effectively opens a new ticket for the team to review

If the bug was reported *more recently* than a year and is still not resolved then gather all of your evidence and post a detailed answer with your reproduction of the issue. At this point you probably want to upvote the question as well. Posting the answer will bump the question in the active list and that should get more attention to it. If it is prevalent then others will upvote it as well and it should get handled depending on severity.

If you reproduced the bug, and the process you used was similar to the question, then posting an answer is probably not the best approach. In this situation, your best option is to upvote, and perhaps edit in some clarifications to the question or a screenshot or something to add to its credibility.

In the end, questions which identify bugs which have low views and low votes and have been around for a long time probably relate to things which are not severe issues. In general, if it is not affecting a large amount of users, it is probably not a major concern and this potentially is why it is still open.

tldr;

Report was > 1 yr old: Repost
Report was < 1 yr old: Answer or edit

---

Also, for reference, here is an instance of this happening to me since examples in the wild are usually preferable in these types of "What if" scenarios. I observed that a comment process had changed and duplication of comment posting was possible on accident.

There was a question stating a similar event but it was a year old. [Two comments add if we press Enter twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222780/two-comments-add-if-we-press-enter-twice?lq=1) . I asked a new question here: [Throttle comment button to prevent double submission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250994/throttle-comment-button-to-prevent-double-submission) .

Once I realized it had been already posted in similar fashion I asked Anna Lear♦ if it should be closed as a duplicate and she responded "That one's a year old and (probably) a different issue. Just stick with this new report" [Throttle comment button to prevent double submission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250994/throttle-comment-button-to-prevent-double-submission#comment819459_250994) .

While this example is not a perfect reproduction of asking first and posting second, it is effectively the same thing. It also allowed for one of the team members to take notice and fix the issue (thanks Jarrod Dixon♦).