# Why is my tag score so low?

Tags: bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

My `C++` tag badge says 49/100. When I click on the settings to choose which badge to follow, it says 97/100.

Is there some hidden sense to this? I would like to understand why my score is only 49, so I can improve it.

Comment: Have you tried selecting a different tag badge and then switching back to the C++ tag badge to see if it updates?

Comment: Thanks @animuson  That helped, but I think it stands as a *bug*

Comment: Out of interest, are you doing this on the mobile app? Because I've noticed that tends to group 'tag score' by questions/answers.

Comment: Just chrome (tablet + desktop)

Comment: Same for me. 886 versus 718. Fixed it by opening the dialog to choose another badge but stuck with the same badge.

Comment: Also for clarification, the next-badge count is the one that is wrong, the score in the list of all tags is correct.

Comment: If you choose the tag that is already selected, the value in the next badge box is updated - so this really seems to be a stale view bug.

Comment: btw, Congratulations on your first tag badge!

Comment: @AngeloFuchs thanks - when it was delivered, the display was correct.

Comment: This actually sounds like another report of [Tag score is shown incorrectly in the next badge tracker section](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305636/tag-score-is-shown-incorrectly-in-the-next-badge-tracker-section)