# Badge tracking bar stuck

Tags: bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

I've noticed that in my account, if I select "Track the next tag badge" the progress bars are not progressing. I know that they doesn't get updated instantly, but, for example, my Java badge has been stuck on 25/100 for weeks. If I click on the gear to choose which badge to track, then it shows the correct progress. Is this a bug? Has anybody else noticed that?

Comment: I've also noticed this. My ruby-on-rails gold tag tracker says 562/1000, as it did when I set the tag tracker, but I actually now have 596 points in the tag.

Comment: Yeah, this has come up [before.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305636/tag-score-is-shown-incorrectly-in-the-next-badge-tracker-section) A number of times, actually. (Check the linked section of that post.)