# The legendary badge is calculated incorrectly when being viewed as your "Next badge"

Tags: bug, reputation, badge-progress, daily-reputation-badges

I'm pretty close to receiving the [legendary badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary), and I noticed that the "Next badge" popup *seems* to calculate today's rep incorrectly.

As you can see, it states that I have 140/200 rep for the day, when I clearly have 185/200.

I highly doubt that this is due to caching because I currently have 3 accepted answers for the day, and 185 - 45 = 140. It seems as though the calculation doesn't take accepted answers into consideration.

I only need 15 more points for the day in order to receive that badge, therefore I assume that this is a bug.

[image: Legendary]

Comment: ["All positive reputation activities, including up votes, accepted answers, bounties, and suggested edits count towards this badge except for association bonuses, which do not count."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/213575) yep, you are right

Comment: Based on [Tag score is shown incorrectly in the next badge tracker section](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305636/tag-score-is-shown-incorrectly-in-the-next-badge-tracker-section), I just assumed the scores in the next badge tracker were *all* wrong.

Comment: This is a 7 year old bug... granted it is not a problem for the vast majority of users, it is a bit frustrating (still working on my Legendary status, 106/150)