# Incorrect score in tag badge (again)

Tags: support, tag-score

Well I have seen many questions about this problem in tag badge score. All point to this one:

[Tag score is shown incorrectly in the next badge tracker section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305636/tag-score-is-shown-incorrectly-in-the-next-badge-tracker-section)

and I found in the comments that if I re-track my badge it will update.

It should be the net upvote value, right? The sum of all upvotes and downvotes.

Now, I have counted my scores on the JavaScript tag back and forth 3 times, and the result should be 25. But the JavaScript tag badge shows 16:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2752520+[javascript]

I have re-tracked my JavaScript badge, I have selected another badge and then re-selected JavaScript, and the score is still 16.

Am I missing something here or this is a bug that's not fixed yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not counting everything correctly.

First, your search query includes all questions and answers.  Your tag score only includes answers, so you need to remove the questions from the list.

Second, your search query includes all posts, including [wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (although you don't have any so this isn't skewing your counts).

And lastly, you seem to be counting incorrectly.  I looked through the same query you used and still only come up to 17 (your post from today won't count in the Tag Score yet).  You should only count the score of your own posts.  The only way I get to 25 is if you count your answer score, your question score, and the number of answers to your questions (basically counting all of the numbers in the left side of the query page.  The number of answers to your posts has no bearing on your tag score.

If you want to verify your own tag score, append `is:answer` and `wiki:no` to the query string to filter your post list to only what counts.

So your javascript query is: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2752520+%5Bjavascript%5D+is%3Aa+wiki%3Ano

Comment: :) understood... thanks. Will try harder :)