# Why is there a difference between tag badge score in graph and tags block?

Tags: bug

In my activity section , the score of `html` tag badge is different in graph and tags section. Below are the screenshots for the same:

**Graph Section**

[image: Graph Section]

**Tag Section**

[image: Tag Section]

Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)... may take a few hours or months to update.

Comment: I have already cleared the cache and this is the same for months. However the tag section gets updated on a regular basis.

Comment: I'm talking about server-side caching; also see here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305636/tag-score-is-shown-incorrectly-in-the-next-badge-tracker-section