# Badge tracking stuck again?

Tags: bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

There's a large discrepancy between badge tracking using track next badge and tag score as shown on the profile and when choosing which badge to track.

[image]

This was an issue [back in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305636/7296893), but got fixed, so it might be a regression.

A gap of 32 questions means that if this is caching, it's likely ~1 month behind, which is too large to be reasonable imo.

On the *Tags* profile page, the correct number shows, just like it did in 2015.

Comment: Hmm... Apparently the cache just got flushed for me (even though I reloaded a couple of times before posting this). Voting to close this as no repro as I can't reproduce this anymore.

Comment: I've got the same issue: https://gyazo.com/88e3016f447bb2afa6cf071ff6b1f576

Comment: @Script47 Huh? That screenshot doesn't relate to my question

Comment: My bad, I misread your question and saw the `badge-progress` tag and noticed an issue with mine and thought it was related. It still seems sort of related to the tracking aspect / badge progress.